# Magento suddenly slow

Tags: magento-1.8, performance, centos

I installed an existing Magento installation on a clean CentOS server.
This installation was running fast, with no problems and without any caching module.

Now, suddenly over the weekend, the speed dropped down from 2s/page to 5s/page.

Where do i have to look for a reason?

Update: I cleared the Magento cache folder, and now it's running fast again. 
How to avoid this in the future?

Comment: what cache backend do you use, and did you clean the cache after install the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Magento 1.8+ I highly recommend you enabled REDIS cache (See KB article [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee))

Here is some great information on speeding up Magento, implement the features that apply:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/36225/

Finally look into optimizing your database using **mysqltuner.pl** and **tuning-primer.sh** Google these and run against your database, follow the recommendations.

You should also configure your store to periodically clean the visitor logs:

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log Cleaning
```

Personal note: I too experienced the same performance drop, implementing a lot of the above helped significantly. You need to keep monitoring your sites performance and adjust settings as necessary.

Good luck!

Comment: I installed APC in the meanwhile. Pageload is now within 2 seconds, so that's good. I also viewed mysqltuner.pl, the only recommendation was to enable slow query log and i see some error: ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 1: Lost connection to MySQL server during query??  Yesterday, suddenly my entire system went down for some reason. I had to restart the system. Now i'm looking for a reason in the logs, but i can't find anything...

Comment: If you are able to access via CLI use the linux `top` command to find any high CPU/Memory processes.

Comment: In my hosting graphs, i see a high CPU peek around the time that the system went down... At this time, there are no high CPU processes.

Comment: I still advise that you go with REDIS, sub-zero page load times are hard to beat. If you have questions about another issue, please feel free to post a new question as it is not related to this one. If I have resolved your issue, kindly mark my answer as the accepted solution. SR

Answer (score 2):

dont use file based caching. this causes many i/o requests which could slow down your application.

Comment: thats nothing a cache clean would fix, as many files on disk dont slow down the cache read magically.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do i have to look for a reason?

This is a bit old but I just had the same problem with `v2.2.7` with a default setup (no REDIS or special mysql optimizations). I've been testing it fine for a few weeks or more and it's been pretty fast. Yesterday, out of nowhere, it got crazy slow.

When i looked at **System > Tools > Cache Management** everything was disabled. I'm not sure how that happened. It's been enabled since install. The only thing I did that day was try to apply a patch (unsuccessfully) but there were no warning or error messages in the console saying cache would be disabled. After re-enabling cache, everything was fast again.